# Eclipse helios issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6

I have installed eclipse Helios c/c++ on my Ubuntu 10.04.
Now I can easily develop c or c++ application.

Now my problem is that I want to use Java on this eclipse.
I know that eclipse is made for Java .
But I use eclipse Helios c/c++(Its a new eclipse for developing c or c++ application).

In this IDE You don't find the option of making Java project .

Can anyone tell me how to write Java application in this IDE( Eclipse -Helios c/c++)?

can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Help menu, then Install New Software.
In the "Work with" box, drop it down and select `Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios`.  Wait for the Name box to populate.  Go down to Programming Languages and click it.
Select "Eclipse Java Development Tools".
[image: Screenshot1]
Click through the installation, selecting that you agree to the license terms (assuming you do).
Restart Eclipse.
In the upper right hand corner, there's a tiny icon that looks like panes of glass, and it probably has an icon next to it that says C/C++.  Click that, and open up the Java perspective.
[image: Screenshot2]